# Alternative to iframe in big project

Tags: asp.net, iframe, web

I have 5 solutions/project in .net. And 1 project "MENU" that contain iframe to call the other five projects. I want to know how to do the same without iframe. What is the best practice to separate the project but create a one big web.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, use usercontrol like this.

```
yourpage.controls.add(new usercontrol("your_user_control_menu.ascx") as usercontrol);
```

Comment: No, because in a big web with 5 projects I can't share the master page across the project and the other side debug the five projects separately